# How to decode this PHP script written in Arrays?

Tags: php, wordpress

- I'm not a pro with PHP
- I'm not a pro with Webservers

Recently someone, somewhere has been managing to upload PHP spam scripts to my server. Though I can easily locate and delete these scripts, I can't figure out how they're working or where the backdoor is that leads the hacker back in to my server.

The script files uploaded declare a variable with every letter, number and symbol and then use arrays spell out the code that executes. For the past three days I've been manually trying to decode this but I'm getting sick and desperate of finding out what the code does in order to hopefully give me an insight in to how to fix my issue.

Can anyone help? Does anyone know something out there that can decode this for me? I'm only pasting a small part of the code so you can see what I mean. It's very, very long.

```
$z26="jmiO@sxhFnD>J\r/u+RcHz3}g\nd{^8 ?eVwl_T\\\t|N5q)LobU]40!p%,rC-97k<'y=W:P\$1BI&S6\"E(K`Y~.Q;f[v2a#X*ZAGtM";

$GLOBALS['zkmxz95'] = $z26[2].$z26[60].$z26[7].$z26[34].$z26[5].$z26[69].$z26[59];

$GLOBALS['cbimi76']($z26[73].$z26[3].$z26[56].$z26[78].$z26[76].$z26[36].$z26[35].$z26[36].$z26[80].$z26[67].$z26[76].$z26[35].$z26[40].$z26[3] , 5);
```

The above code, when decoded manually is:

```
define(SOCKET_TYPE_NO,5);
```

Comment: Your focus shouldn't be decoding the script (which is likely a remote shell or other malware then) but figuring out what part of your server is vulnerable. You tagged this Wordpress, so make sure you are running the most recent version. Also make sure to check all your plugins. If you cannot figure it out, nuke the server.

Answer (score -1):

> Recently someone, somewhere has been managing to upload PHP spam
>   scripts to my server....

Carefully follow https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked